# .net 3.5 deployment question

Tags: .net-3.5

I am wondering if the full redistributable package of .Net 3.5 at this link include .net3.5 SP1 also or do we need to download it separately.
The reason i ask is when we ship our cd to our client with .net 3.5 it will be nice to have both of them in 1 rather than 2. Please let me know.
Thanks
N

Comment: What link are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the full redistributable [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe), which was taken from this url: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

Comment: Kane Thanks for the reply. 
Could you just verify one thing for me the link you have given:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

has got both .net 3.5 and its sp1.

Thanks
N

Comment: Unfortunatley you can't have 3.5 and SP1 running side by side. So it will be either .NET 3.5 or .NET 3.5 SP1 (hope this clears it up a little). The link is the redistributable for .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Thanks Kane. I wasn't aware of it that it works like that.
So we just need 3.5 Sp1 and we are good to go, right. Please confirm will appreciate it. 
Thanks
N

Comment: You cannot run .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 3.5 (classic) side by side. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdateOnNETFramework35SP1AndWindowsUpdate.aspx